# There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'org.alamofire.Alamofire' under the iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage

I recently updated a project to Xcode 12 and I had to update carthage to 0.37. When I did that, build was fine but when I tried to push the app to the testflight, I got this error:

```
    ERROR ITMS-90685: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. 
    There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 
    'org.alamofire.Alamofire' under the iOS application '
```

This issue happens because I do not know how to set the frameworks come from carthage "Do not embed". In the carthage docs, they say that remove the copy-frameworks script and there is no alternative or a new way to copy frameworks as I see. How can I copy the xcframeworks without embedding in Xcode?

**Solution:**

After some investigation and trying different solutions, I decided to use pods in my SDK and that solved my problem. Pods can be not embedded so I could able to push an app to the store without any error.